# positioning an image after a class

Tags: html, css

I'm using a class to style some text and what I want to place an image just after the class (to the right of the text) and, obviously!, I'm struggling. Here's what I've got so far.

```
<a href="#" class="tickbutton">Check your eligibility and apply now!</a>

.tickbutton {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #5460ac url(../../images/tick.png) no-repeat right;
background-position:150% 50%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
width:auto;
}
```

This places the image (a transparent tick) inside the container and I'd like to position it just to the right. I've tried using tickbutton:after but that still inherits the background color so it 'appears' to still be inside the container.

Is this doable?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: did you try change your background-position values and see where it goes?

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the background color when using tickbutton:after?

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://tinkerbin.com/8v8Umjug)? Than you need to use `background-position: -1 0;` and add a `padding-right` of the images `width` + some extra space for example